# Merge tool for c# code

Tags: merge, diff

Can anyone recommend a merge tool that's specifically designed for merging C# code? The features I'm after:

- Can identify code constructs (classes, methods, ...)
- Can detect reorders of those constructs
- Ignore reorder-only differences
- 3-way merge
- Compilation errors highlighted on-the-fly in the result pane.

Basically, I'm looking for a tool that's much more specific than classic file merge tools like Winmerge. The problem with general-purpose merge tools is that they detect changes line by line which makes it extremely hard to identify blocks of code that has been moved around but that are still perfectly valid, and more importantly, to identify compilation errors in the result.

Comment: Well, his question addresses a common problem, especially with automatic code reformatting. Highlighting of compilation errors really doesn't fit into a merge tool, but his other points are very valid.

Comment: @MitchWheat - People probably like the idea of a context sensitive merge tool. I believe one calls it a programmer.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Your comments are disrespectful. Automatic code reformatting doesn't only introduce white spaces. It might introduce braces, rename variables etc. See ReSharpers Clean Code feature for example. Furthermore, all this has nothing to do with a magic teapot. It can be achieved be creating a merge tool that doesn't compare characters but code entities.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: if you are using a tool (such as Resharper) to change the code, then you better not ignore those changes in a diff tool.

Comment: Eclipse does much of what the OP asks for, but as far as I can tell not for C#...

Comment: I can't understand usage of `automatic code reformatting` in merge tool, when resharper or other tools are available to this, Also this makes code harder to merge, i.e I usually do it after merging, it cause to have a good history of code.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I don't see your point. If you want to merge *functional changes* (or see them), a tool like the one the OP asked about is very handy. Especially in environments where there is no coding standard established.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Nobody asked for a merge tool that does automatic code reformatting.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, as I can see you asked it in your comments. "especially with automatic code reformatting"

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: No. Please read my comments again. The OP is asking for a tool that can compare the code entities (or code constructs as he calls them) and not the characters itself. One use case of this is to see only the real changes in a code file in which real changes have been made as well as automatic changes using a automatic code reformatter. Nobody ever talked about the merge tool doing the code reformatting - except you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [Code Compare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/)? 
The features you asked for are in the Pro Edition (see [feature comparison](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/featurematrix.html)) which is 49.90$.

Comment: CodeCompare looks like a good fit for the requirements listed in my question. I'm currently trialing it. Thanks.

Comment: It looks good, but it is slow to work with. Also the interface is a little cluttered as there are way too many UI elements overlaid on the code.